# Regex syntax to match equal sign in each word but do not take in consideration the first equal sign

Tags: python, regex

It might be confusing and I don't know if it even possible as I have some knowledge about regex using python but I couldn't solve the issue I have.

The thing is I have logs that I want to replace the equal sign in their URL to their url encoding (`%3D`) using Regex syntax.

For example I have logs of this:

```
request=www.google.com/fgdsg=gfsdg=gfdsd
request_access=https://regex101.com/eawf/?=dasf
```

All the equal sign after the first one that uses to assign value for variable I want to match them then replace them with `%3D` like this:

```
request=www.google.com/fgdsg%3Dgfsdg%3Dsgfdsd
request_access=https://regex101.com/eawf/?%3Ddasf
```

This is what I want to be.
The written text it only example I didn't wrote real logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a negative lookbehind like so: `(?<!request)=` this will match all the `=` that do not come after `request`. A little

```py
import re
sample = "request=www.google.com/fgdsg=gfsdg=gfdsd"
replaced = re.sub('(?<!request)=', '%3D', sample)
print(replaced)
```

Comment: Tried this solution and work, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the part before (including) the first `=`, leaving only the request URL. Then you can simply substitute all occurrences of `=` with `%3D` in this string.

```py
import re
log = "request=www.google.com/fgdsg=gfsdg=gfdsd"
request_url = re.sub(r'^\w+=', '', log, 1)
urlencoded_request_url = re.sub(r'=', '%3D', request_url)
print(urlencoded_request_url)  # www.google.com/fgdsg%3Dgfsdg%3Dgfdsd
```

Comment: No regular expression needed; just use `_, request_url = log.split('=', 1)` and `urlencoded_request_url = request_url.replace('=', '%3D')`.

Comment: The `re` package is part of the standard library and I find it easier to handle.